# SSRS: Union data from multiple databases

Tags: sql, sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I am working on a reporting scenario where I need to query multiple databases (for the same product) and show it in a single dashboard. The dashboard is on SSRS.

Connecting to multiple databases is not a challenge.

How can I be able to do an union of the two datasets on SSRS? I need to show some grouping and charts etc on the merged data. The merging is basically just UNION.

I was reading DPE (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms152816%28v=sql.105%29.aspx). If I get some clue, I can start on this.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Are you have trouble with the UNION/UNION ALL statement?

Comment: @SpaceghostAli, the problem is not UNION ALL. The problem is that I want to bring in the data from two different SQL Server databases. Its like select from DB1.Tbl UNION ALL Select from DB2.tbl and the DB1 and DB2 are from different database instances in different servers et al.

Comment: @Kangkan did you solve this. I have the same issue

Comment: @KeithL Here lies the solution that I approached: https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/31728.ssrs-merge-data-from-different-data-sources-into-one-data-set-inside-ssrs-report-using-xml-connection.aspx

However, it is too long and I really forgot the final stage.

Comment: Wow - this is going to be easier than trying to fix my double hop problem regarding a linked server. @Kangkan -- I think you should post that as your accepted answer.

Comment: @KeithL Added that as an answer. Do let me know if that finally helps.

Answer (score 0):

i assure this can be succeeded using lookup:
for more detailed ddescription please refer this blog.

[Click Here](http://www.allaboutmssql.com/2013/08/ssrs-example-for-lookup-lookupset-and.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can create a [linked server](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa560998.aspx) and then reference both databases in a single query like:

```
select ... from server1.dbo.tbl1 union all select ... from server2.dbo.tbl2
```

Comment: We do not have the option to create linked server on the database. That might be the last option at this moment. What I am interested is if we can do something that is transparent to the database?

Answer (score 0):

This might help others, so adding it as an answer.

I could resolve this by following the steps here:  http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/31728.ssrs-merge-data-from-different-data-sources-into-one-data-set-inside-ssrs-report-using-xml-connection.aspx

Comment: The problem with this is that the question asks how to do a UNION and the solution in the article isn't a UNION, but more like a JOIN.